# C# Union Structure Marshalling

Tags: c#, mono, marshalling, ioctl

I'm trying to integrate Video4Linux in my managed application. Indeed I've declared all required structures and relative *ioctl*. In this question I present two `ioctl`: `SetFormat` and `GetFormat`; while the former is working well (like the other dozen I actually use), the latter is returning me bad memory behavior.

The `GetFormat` ioctl is actually performing, but as soon the application is accessing to the ioctl parameter (either debugger or my application itself), it always crashes with following stack:

```
System.NullReferenceException: ...
at System.String.mempy4(...) in <filename unknown>:0
at System.String.memcpy(...) in <filename unknown>:0
at Derm.Platform.Video4Linux.ControlGetFormat(...) in <...>
...
```

I had some investigation on [p/invoking ioctl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387603/p-invoke-ioctl-system-call), and again, I cannot understand why my application is crashing. I suspect it's becuase structure memory layout, but I cannot explain why `SetFormat` is working while `GetFormat` don't (since they use the very same parameter).

I have to P/Invoke a `ioctl` routine that receive/return the structure `v4l2_format`:

```
struct v4l2_format {
        enum v4l2_buf_type type;
        union {
                struct v4l2_pix_format          pix;     /* V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE */
                struct v4l2_pix_format_mplane   pix_mp;  /* V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE_MPLANE */
                struct v4l2_window              win;     /* V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_OVERLAY */
                struct v4l2_vbi_format          vbi;     /* V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VBI_CAPTURE */
                struct v4l2_sliced_vbi_format   sliced;  /* V4L2_BUF_TYPE_SLICED_VBI_CAPTURE */
                __u8    raw_data[200];                   /* user-defined */
        } fmt;
};

struct v4l2_pix_format {
    __u32                   width;
    __u32                   height;
    __u32                   pixelformat;
    enum v4l2_field         field;
    __u32                   bytesperline;   /* for padding, zero if unused */
    __u32                   sizeimage;
    enum v4l2_colorspace    colorspace;
    __u32                   priv;           /* private data, depends on pixelformat */
};
```

I've traduced the structure `v4l2_format` using the following form

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 4, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Format
{
    public Format(BufferType bufferType)
    {
        Type = bufferType;
        Pixmap = new PixmapFormat();
        RawData = new byte[RawDataLength];
    }

    public Format(BufferType bufferType, PixmapFormat pixmapFormat)
    {
        Type = bufferType;
        Pixmap = pixmapFormat;
        RawData = new byte[RawDataLength];
    }

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public BufferType Type;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public PixmapFormat Pixmap;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=RawDataLength)]
    public byte[] RawData;

    public const int RawDataLength = 200;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public struct PixmapFormat
{
    public PixmapFormat(uint width, uint height, PixelFormatCode pixelFormat)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        PixelFormat = pixelFormat;
        Field = Video4Linux.BufferField.Any;
        BytesPerLine = 0;
        SizeImage = 0;
        Colorspace = Video4Linux.PixelColorspace.None;
        Private = 0;
    }

    public UInt32 Width;

    public UInt32 Height;

    public PixelFormatCode PixelFormat;

    public BufferField Field;

    public UInt32 BytesPerLine;

    public UInt32 SizeImage;

    public PixelColorspace Colorspace;

    public UInt32 Private;
}
```

And finally, here is the methods calling ioctl:

```
public static void ControlGetFormat(IntPtr fd, BufferType pixmapType, out PixmapFormat pixmapFormat)
{
    if (fd == IntPtr.Zero)
        throw new ArgumentException("invalid file descriptor", "fd");

    Format format = new Format(pixmapType);

    int result = IoCtrlGetFormat(fd, GetFormat.ControlCode, ref format);

    if (result < 0)
        ThrowExceptionOnError();

    pixmapFormat = format.Pixmap;
}

private static readonly IoCtrlRequest GetFormat = new IoCtrlRequest(IoCtrlDirection.Read | IoCtrlDirection.Write, 'V', 4, typeof(Format));

[DllImport("libc", EntryPoint = "ioctl", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int IoCtrlGetFormat(IntPtr fd, Int32 code, ref Format argument);

public static void ControlSetFormat(IntPtr fd, BufferType pixmapType, ref PixmapFormat pixmapFormat)
{
    if (fd == IntPtr.Zero)
        throw new ArgumentException("invalid file descriptor", "fd");

    PixmapFormat pixmapFormatCopy = pixmapFormat;
    Format format = new Format(pixmapType, pixmapFormatCopy);

    int result = IoCtrlSetFormat(fd, SetFormat.ControlCode, ref format);

    if (result < 0)
        ThrowExceptionOnError();

    pixmapFormat = format.Pixmap;
}

private static readonly IoCtrlRequest SetFormat = new IoCtrlRequest(IoCtrlDirection.Read | IoCtrlDirection.Write, 'V', 5, typeof(Format));

[DllImport("libc", EntryPoint = "ioctl", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int IoCtrlSetFormat(IntPtr fd, Int32 code, ref Format argument);
```

Comment: I don't think a union with Explicit can work when one of the fields is an object. I'd try using sequential layout and just declare the array field. Then use Marshal class to read/write other fields.

Comment: Except the array, everything is a structure. Is it possible to force the structure size, excluding the array field?

Comment: I'd be very tempted to wrap the v4l structures into ones that are simpler to pinvoke and have an unmanaged function to translate between them

Comment: @IanNorton I've already tried, but I gived up: V4L layer is really a video demuxer plugin integrated as plugin, and my plugin system is not allowing easy unmanaged plugins. Indeed I decided to get back to the managed solution.

Comment: "Is it possible to force the structure size, excluding the array field?" Use the Size parameter to the StructLayout attribute

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This has solved the question: removing `RawData` field and setting up `StructLayout.Size = 204` has solved nicely the problem! I think this merits a answer!

Comment: @Luca Please feel free to add an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has been solved by forcing the structure size to the actual one (*204*, in my case), and remove the array field `RawData` (as suggested by [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan)).

Indeed:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 4, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Size = 204)]
public struct Format
{
    public Format(BufferType bufferType)
    {
        Type = bufferType;
        Pixmap = new PixmapFormat();
    }

    public Format(BufferType bufferType, PixmapFormat pixmapFormat)
    {
        Type = bufferType;
        Pixmap = pixmapFormat;
    }

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public BufferType Type;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public PixmapFormat Pixmap;
}
```

Of course, `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Format)) == 204`.